# Unable to trigger custom (manual) Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Im trying to get custom bitbucket pipeline to work. Here are my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

Them same steps I did for auto pipeline is working fine. Im just trying to get manual pipeline to work.

I also checked the documentation, doesnt seem like there anything mention about `import`

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  custom:
    staging-deploy:
      deploy:
        - step:
          name: Deploy to DockerHub
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - export IMAGE_NAME=$DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/$PROJECT_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
            - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
            - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
            - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
        
        - step:
          name: Deploy to Droplet
          script:
            - export IMAGE_NAME=$DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/$PROJECT_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.6.1
              variables:
                SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
                SERVER: $SSH_SERVER
                COMMAND: 'docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD; docker pull $IMAGE_NAME; docker stop $PROJECT_NAME; docker rm $PROJECT_NAME; docker run -d --restart always --name $PROJECT_NAME -p $SERVER_PORT:$SERVER_PORT $IMAGE_NAME; docker image prune -a -f'
```

For context

1. Build image and push the image to DockerHub
2. SSH to DO Droplet and pull the image from DockerHub and run the image

But Im getting this error when Im trying to trigger it in Pipeline UI

```
There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > custom > staging-deploy]. Required attributes are not set: import 
Find out more
```

[image: Bitbucket Pipeline error]

Answer (score 1):

2 things that I needed to fix

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    staging-deploy:
      deploy:    # This need to be remove
        - step:
          name: Deploy to DockerHub # This need 2 indent
          services:
            - docker
```

Here are the fixed YAML

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    staging-deploy:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to DockerHub # This have 2 indent (very important)
          deplyment: staging
          services:
            - docker
```